# Phonegap Only 1 buttonIndex is working in Notification.confirm

Tags: ios, cordova, web-applications, notifications, confirm

I'm using the Phonegap 'confirm' in iOS.

When to use 'confirm', two buttons shown, but to be working only 1 button.

[Yes, No] button.

if the 'Yes' button is pressed only 'callback' function is activated and

'No' button nothing happens..

What should I do?

My Code>>

```
video.addEventlistener("ended",function(){
    console.log('onended');
    navigator.notification.confirm(
        'Exit?',
        onConfirm,
        'Done',
        ['Yes','No']
    );
}, false);

function onConfirm(button){
    console.log(button);
    if(button == 1){
        location.href = history.go(-1);
    }else if(button == 2){
        ...
    }
}
```

if I clicked Yes button, log displayed 1.

if I clicked No button, log not displayed nothing.

**Phonegap 2.9.1 version**

I had to use 'string' on button name. 
but deprecated happens. solved to use 'array'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 function onConfirm(buttonIndex) {
        alert('You selected button ' + buttonIndex);
    }
```

This way, try getting index of both button (Yes and No) and accordingly you can define your conditional logic.

Comment: OMG! It's Working! How the hell did this happen?   had displaying alert window after code running!
code is wrong.. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing this on a real device? I always have trouble emulating iOS devices, because the application stops working after only one interaction. What happens if you press 'No' first?

Comment: This should probably be a comment and not a full answer

Comment: you need rep to comment :(